# How to troubleshoot Python Symbol not found error (PythonMagick)

Tags: python

I've installed the PythonMagick module but I get the following error when I try to execute a python file that imports it:

```
  File "process_images.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PythonMagick
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PythonMagick/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import _PythonMagick
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PythonMagick/_PythonMagick.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN6Magick8Geometry4yOffEl
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PythonMagick/_PythonMagick.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PythonMagick/_PythonMagick.so
```

I'm not sure what steps I can take from here to troubleshoot.

Using MacOS Sierra (10.12.5), Python 2.7.10

If it helps, I used the following instructions to install PythonMagick: https://gist.github.com/tomekwojcik/2778301#gistcomment-1614534

Comment: Give us some of your actual code, so we can look at it to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @SH7890 The code that's failing is `import PythonMagick`. From what I can tell there's something wrong in the module, not the code that implements it.

Comment: I don't know. Looking at the link you posted, it looks like there are many problems with this module. Don't know if you've tried this or not, but you could ask the guy who made it, since it seems to be riddled with issues.